# Readjusting nanoScroller when new data is added.

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, nanoscroller

Im using angular nanoscroller which is a wrapper for nanoScrollerJS:
https://github.com/maxaon/angular-nanoscroller

I want the scrollbar to automatically adjust itself to the top of the point where the new data is added (when it is added), right now when new data is added to the list the scrollbar stays at the same place.

I want to achieve something like this with this scrollbar:

https://sroze.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/demo_async.html

Comment: ANd what have you tried so far?

Comment: can you please give me a starting point, if you have anything in mind? cant really think of anything?